# Keyboard shortcut for Windows explorer context menu items

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have a few custom context menu items in Windows Explorer added through Registry keys.

Is it possibble to assign a keyboard shortcut to these menu items?

I have a new programmable keyboard from X-Keys in which I want to assign a key to run my context menu item when clicked however the only way to do it so far is to make a mouse click occur at an absolute or relative pixel count from where a click event occurs.  This will not work though as the context menu position is different depending where the file is located on the screen.

So if there is a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to menu items then it would be perfect!

Answer (score 5):

Add an ampersand `&` in the title before the character you'd like as the shortcut key.  Then you can press the <kbd>letter</kbd> as a shortcut key.

For example, `Pla&y` should show up with the y underlined, and pressing <kbd>y</kbd> would activate the command.

Comment: My windows explorer context menus don't currently have any letters assigned see image here please: http://i.imgur.com/Swc49LG.png - Also this line `dd an ampersand & in the title before the character you'd like as the shortcut key` Where did you mean that this should be added at?  In the Registry?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, include this change in the Registry entry.  It should be in the text string displayed in the context menu.  "Play &with Cherry Player" should underline the w.

Comment: So far I'm not having much luck.  `Open Web Browser on &Dev Server G` is the string in registry I edited adding the `&` before the `D` which resulted in my context menu looking like this: http://i.imgur.com/LW8gvA3.png

Comment: Another update.  As the image above shows there is no underline however pressing keys `shift + d` does in fact select the menu item!  So that does seem to work!  Just note of the `shift` instead of `alt` keys